# Python Lists: .lower() attribute error

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a program on python to do with manipulating lists/arrays. I am having trouble with an error:

> `lowercase = names.lower`
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

I really need some help to fix this!

```
names = [] #Declares an array
print("Type menu(), to begin")
def menu():

    print("----------------------------MENU-----------------------------")
    print("Type: main() for core functions")
    print("Type: delete() to delete a name")
    print("Type: save() to save the code")
    print("Type: load() to load the saved array")
    print("Type: lower() to make all items in the list lower case")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------")

def main():
    times = int(input("How many names do you want in the array? ")) #Asks the user how many names they want in the array
for i in range(times):
    names.append(input("Enter a name ")) #Creates a for loop that runs for the amount of times the user requested, it asks the user to enter the names
choice = input("Would you like the array printed backwards? ") #asks the user whether they want the array backwards
if choice == "Yes":
    names.reverse() #If the user says yes, the array is reversed then printed backwards
    print(names)
else:
    print(names) #Otherwise, the array is printed normally
number = int(input("Which item would you like to print out? "))
number = number - 1
print(names[number])
start = int(input("What is the first position of the range of items to print out? "))
start = start - 1
end = int(input("What is the last position of the range of items to print out? "))
print(names[start:end])

def delete():
    takeAway = input("Which name would you like to remove? ")
    names.remove(takeAway)
    print(names)

def save():
    saving1 = open("Save.txt", 'w')
    ifsave = input("Would you like to save the array? ")
    if ifsave == "Yes":
        for name in names:
                saving1.write("%s\n" % name)
                saving1.close
    else:
        menu()
def load():
    loadquestion = input("Would you like to load a list of names? ")
    if loadquestion == "Yes":
        saving1 = open('Save.txt', 'r')
        print(saving1.read())
        saving1.close()
    else:
        menu()
def lower():
    lowerq = input("Would you like to make the array lowercase? ")
    if lowerq == "Yes":
        lowercase = names.lower
        print(lowercase)
    else:
        menu()
```

Comment: Please learn to provide a [mcve], instead of dumping all your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says, you can't use `.lower()` on lists, only on strings. That means you'll have to iterate over the list and use `.lower()` on every list item:

```
lowercase = [x.lower() for x in names]
```

Comment: Another thing to note is that he wasn't actually *calling* `.lower` anyway; he was just mentioning it.  A second way to do it would be to use `map()`: `lowercase = map(str.lower, names)`.

Comment: also, since this user is obviously new to python, it might be helpful to write out what this list comp actually does:
`lowercase = []
for x in names: # iterates over list of names
 lowercase.append(x.lower())`

Answer (score 3):

The variable `names` is a list. You can't use the `.lower()` method on a list.

pp_ provided the solution:

```
lowercase = [x.lower() for x in names]
```

While not ***exactly*** equivalent to the previous example, this may read better to you and has, effectively, the same result:

```
lowercase=[]
for name in names:
    lowercase.append(name.lower())
```

Alternate solution that may fit your needs:

```
print (str(names).lower())
```